# How to use same function on same element multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a button in a table and my button is a single element but on top, I am changing the row of the table based on some condition, so when my final table created is I see button in all rows, which is fine and as per the requirement.

Now I need to use a function on button click which I want to perform the same action in each row to remove the row where the button is placed. when I am using a single function it's working only for first time and not after that, how can I use the same function for all buttons?

here is my code:

```
  function AddValueinrow() {
     if(anotherTeamname=='DEV'){

     if(selectedValue=="dummy value1"){

        row = document.getElementById("DEVFirstrow");
     }

     if(selectedValue=="dummy value2"){
        row = document.getElementById("DEVSecondrow");
     }

    var w = row.insertCell(6);
    w.innerHTML = '<button onclick="Releaseentry()" type="button" id="show" class="btn btn-primary">Release</button>';

   }
```

---

```
  function Releaseentry() {

     if(anotherTeamname=='DEV'){

         if(selectedValue=="dummy value1"){
           $('#DEVmyTable > tr').eq(0).children('td').remove();
         }

         if(selectedValue=="dummy value 2"){
           $('#DEVmyTable > tr').eq(1).children('td').remove();
         }

      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the parent row by using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), and remove it.

**Note:** Instead of using inline onclick calls, use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach a single event handler to the container, and react to button clicks.

```js
$('#table').on('click', 'button', function() {
  $(this)
    .closest('tr')
    .children('td:not(:last-child)')
    .remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>td11</td><td>td12</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Release</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td21</td><td>td22</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Release</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td31</td><td>td32</td>
      <td class="button">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Release</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```